# I want to cut and paste paragraphs of txt file to new number of files

Tags: java

consider the content of text file is like:

> java is a programming language and a platform.Java is a high level,
>   robust, secured and object-oriented programming language.
>
> Platform: Any hardware or software environment in which a program
>   runs, is known as a platform. Since Java has its own runtime
>   environment (JRE) and API, it is called platform.
>
> Java history is interesting to know. The history of java starts from
>   Green Team. Java team members (also known as Green Team), initiated a
>   revolutionary task to develop a language for digital devices such as
>   set-top boxes, televisions etc.

now as you can see there are three paragphs. I want to store these three paragraphs in 3 different txt files.

Comment: What code do you already have, what do you need specifically?

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need to read the file in using a `FileReader` and store it as a `String`. You can then use `String.split("\n\n")` to split it into paragraphs (this will give you an array with 3 elements).

You can then loop through each of those array elements, creating a `PrintWriter` for each (to write each array element to a separate file.)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
public void readFileParagraphs(String fileName) throws IOException {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append("\n");
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    // Split the content of the file into an array of paragraphs
    String parags[]= sb.toString().split("\n\n"); 
    //Write every paragraph to a new file
    for (int i=0; i<parags.length();i++) {
        File file = new File("Paragraph_"+i+".txt");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(writer);
        output.print(parags[i]);
        output.close();
    }
} finally {
    br.close();
}
}
```

You have to:

- Read the first file text and store it in a String.
- Split it using a new line regex to get the paragraphs.
- And finally save every result(paragraph) of the split in a new file.